# "The column cannot be modified[ Column name = id ]" when insert one record

Tags: windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce, datacontext

i have create a database on windows phone 7 platform. one of table's defined as follow.

```
[Table]
public class Playlist : BaseTable
{
    // Define ID: private field, public property, and database column.
    private int _id;

    [Column(DbType = "INT NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsDbGenerated = false, CanBeNull=false, IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanging("PlaylistId");
            _id = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("PlaylistId");
        }
    }
    // some other field
    //.......
```

}

i don't want the field "id" is gererated by db, so the "IsDbGenerated = false", but i got an exception when insert one record:
      db.Playlists.InsertOnSubmit(new Playlist { Id = (int)DefalutPlaylist.Default, Name = "default playlist", Group = 0, Type = 0 });

it said "The column cannot be modified[ Column name = id ]"

who can help me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drop "INDENTITY" value in DbType as follow:

```
[Column(DbType = "INT NOT NULL", IsDbGenerated = false, CanBeNull=false, IsPrimaryKey = true)]
```

Cheers

Comment: This does not work for me in WP8, I still get this exception... Any thoughts?